# Is there any replacement for "Lookupset" function in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

I need below type of expression to be implemented in SSRS 2005, but i don't find "Lookupset" function in SSRS 2005.
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!State_ID.Value, Fields!State_ID.Value,Fields!city.Value,"DataSet2"),",") 
Any workaround to achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of doing this is to create a sub-report with the data you want, which appears to be the City/Cities.  In your example, you would create a report that takes a State_ID parameter to filter down to only cities with that State_ID. In your main report with the sub-report in the table you would pass in Fields!State_ID.Value as the parameter.